# Python3 While Syntax-Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, while-loop, syntax-error

I've been at this for hours, searching the questions and even asking my brother, who's a Senior in EE, and even he's stumped. This is for a project due tonight before midnight and I can't seem to get rid of this error. Can anyone take a look at my code and figure out why I keep getting this error? Thank you, and yes, they are indented properly below the while statement.

```
# Initialize Variables
count = 0

#First Customer Input
cus = input("Enter customer's name: ")
custype = input("Enter customer's service type (R for Residential. B for Business): ")
location = input("Enter customer's service location (C for City. P for Parish): ")
kwh = eval(input("Enter customer's number of Kilowatt Hours Used: ")

#Repeat loop based on input items NOT being the sentinel value
while (count < 10):
    if custype == 'R' and location1 == 'C':
        rate = residentialCity
    elif custype == 'R' and location1 == 'P':
        rate = residentialParish
    elif custype == 'B' and location1 == 'C' or 'P':
        rate = business
```

Comment: Could you edit your post to contain the exact indenting in your code?  Python is pretty picky about it.  It does look like you are missing a closing parentheses in the `kwh = eval(input...` line.  That is a really bad idea BTW.

Comment: Your code was not formatted to appear as code (we've fixed it for you). To format code properly, select it and click the `{}` icon, or indent it 4 columns.

Comment: @D.Shawley is right. If you want to input a number, use `int(input(…))` or `float(input(…))`. There's a reason Python got rid of the auto-evaluating input function in 3.0; don't bring it back.

Comment: `eval` is bad for the health of your program!!

Comment: The `while` loop is infinite -- unless there is a code that you did not show.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo.

Answer (score 5):

```
kwh = eval(input("Enter customer's number of Kilowatt Hours Used: ")
```

Count the parentheses.

And as D.Shawley points out in a comment, passing user input to `eval` can do arbitrarily bad things. Why are you using `eval` there anyway?

Comment: In general, any time you have a `SyntaxError` on a line that looks perfectly valid, and you keep getting the same `SyntaxError` no matter how much you strip out of that line, and the same line copied and pasted elsewhere is fine… the problem is that the line above it is missing a closing paren, bracket, brace, or quote (or has a stray backslash).

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. I can't believe I missed that, although, to be a little fair to me, that was 4 lines up from the 'error.'

Comment: @DanielBoudreaux: This is one of those things you learn after debugging it a few times, and then it becomes second nature. Hopefully having been _told_ the trick, you'll only need to go through it once.

Answer (score 3):

As the answer above states, you're missing one parentheses there:

```
kwh = eval(input("Enter customer's number of Kilowatt Hours Used: ")
```

Why would you need an `eval` statement? Seems like you're expecting a number, and want to change the string to an integer. Why not do it like this?

```
kwh = int(input("Enter customer's number of Kilowatt Hours Used: "))
```

Just an advice, but unless there's no better way, don't use `eval`. It's insecure and unstable, somebody can accidentally, or not, input a code and mess with your program.

Comment: Someone already wrote the answer to the question, and comments took care of the use of eval. You even referenced the other answer. This answer provides no real value, and that's why I'm downvoting.

Comment: Well, in my defense, i only suggest him to use `int`, because that probably what he wanted.

Comment: I value your opinion though. Thanks.

Comment: Usually I don't mind answers that provide extra info - but the comments on the question itself provided that extra detail, making this answer (IMO) unnecessary, even though it's good advice. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, i made a same mistake with the OP.. hahaha